# custom css for google search box

Tags: css, search, google-search

On the site I'm trying to build (https://www.dynomotion.com/test/index-search.htm) I have 2 problems:

1. the cursor does not focus exactly within the search box
2. there is no 1px grey bottom border

Does anybody know I have done wrong?

For the styling of the search, I use the following css:

```
#cse-search-form {
   position: relative;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0;
   -moz-border-radius: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   background: #f2f2f2;
   padding: 0;
   margin:0;
}

.gsc-search-box-tools .gsc-search-box .gsc-input .gsc-input-box,
.gsc-search-box-tools .gsc-search-box .gsc-input .gsc-input-box-focus {
    height: 25px;  
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Any pointers would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The cursor does show, but your input element is not positioned correctly. [See here](https://i.imgur.com/4JhWBgg.png)

Comment: Your input element has a table in it...

Comment: You are right: cursor shows, but is not positioned correctly.  As far as I can see, the css only says the search field should have a height of 15px, plus 3px padding.  Where and how can I specify the cursor position?

Comment: Hi!  I still have not resolved this issue.  Can anybody please help?  There must be two conflicting styles or something that the cursor does not go inside the the search box.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem you are facing. First of all, I would like you to suggest using the google developers tool for resolving such problems. Now see here what's the actual problem in the search bar.

Your search bar input is inside the table inside  with class

```
.gsib_a {
    padding: 5px 9px 4px 9px;
}
```

[image: 5 px paddingtop is pushing your inputarea] See the image for reference.

It has padding to 5 px so the padding-top is pushing the input area below.

overwrite this class with:-

```
.gsib_a {
    padding: 0px 9px 4px 9px;
}
```

This is the input area with 0px padding-top. Here is the image reference [image: Input cursor is in middle as padding-top of is 0px]

Now why there is no grey bottom border.

Your div with class <div class="gsc-input-box> has height 25px and its hiding your input area bottom border.

This is the CSS applied currently

```
gsc-search-box-tools .gsc-search-box .gsc-input .gsc-input-box, .gsc-search-box-tools .gsc-search-box .gsc-input .gsc-input-box-focus {
    height: 25px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Image for reference [image: Hiding Bottom grey Border]

Now the solution for this:

remove the height of div:
overwrite this CSS as

```
.gsc-search-box-tools .gsc-search-box .gsc-input .gsc-input-box, .gsc-search-box-tools .gsc-search-box .gsc-input .gsc-input-box-focus {
    /* height: 25px; */ remove this height
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1;
    border: 2x solid #dadada;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Resolved Image : [image: Both of your problem resolved]

Remove the height of div.

Wallah! resolved your issue.

Note: Learn using Google Developers Tools It's really help full for web developers, Regards Badal Sherpa

Comment: Thank you, Badal! That did the trick.  While I'm very grateful (and will use Google Developer Tool), I'm wondering if there is a way to lower the height of the search box - it is too tall right now.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: To change the height of the search box set this class font-size according to your preference. Currently font-size applied is 16px, setting it 10px makes its height smaller .gsc-input {
    font-size: 10px;
}. Do accept the answer if this helps you. Regards Badal Sherpa

Comment: Hi Badal, adding "font-size: 10px;" to the input class (or even the entire search div) did not change anything.

Comment: But I guess I'm not clear on a more fundamental issue: the 16px font size is defined in Google's style sheet.  I thought I can (partly) overwrite that with my own style-search.css, but it does not seem to work...

Comment: Create an inline CSS to overwrite those styles

Comment: You can also overwrite by putting !important flag `.gsc-input {
 font-size: 10px !important;
}` .But before applying this make sure you have followed all the mentioned steps in the post.